# Excel VBA Use SQL to select records and move them to another sheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba

In my macro, I'm using SQL to select a subset of records on a worksheet and move them to another worksheet (in the same workbook).  It works great and puts the data in the first 5 columns on the 2nd worksheet.  This is the code I'm using:

```
vsql = "SELECT [Field1],[Field2],[Field3],[Field4],[Field5] FROM [TestData$] WHERE [Level] IN ('Level 1', 'Level 3', 'Level 4')"
```

I have to move these columns around as the report is putting data from a second source in between some of these columns.

I'm wondering if there is a way to put the results into specific columns instead of the 1st 5 columns on the second worksheet when the SQL is executed?

For example:

Field 1 should be in column 3 instead of column 1
Field 2 should be in column 4 instead of column 2
Field 3 should be in column 7 instead of column 3
Field 4 should be in column 10 instead of column 4
Field 5 should be in column 14 instead of column 5

I've tried adding [], [ ], [""] and [Null] to the SQL to indicate a blank field but all of these prevented the SQL from executing.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you might have.....

Comment: Have you tried using Null or '' without the square brackets?

Comment: @JoeJ............I have not but I'll give them a try.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @JoeJ.................Null works exactly like I want it to and puts the data in the correct columns.  Thanks for your help.  That is going to start the weekend off on a good note!.  Thanks again............